# MySQL subquery using ALL

Tags: mysql, subquery

Relevant schema:

```
courier(courid:int,courname:str)
city(cid:int,cname:str,zid:int) #zid belonging to some table named zone
courierservice(courid:int,cid:int)
```

So the obvious relationship is courier 'serving' cities. I've been trying to get all couriers serving 'both' cities with cname as A and B.
i.e. a possible intersection.

I could get a workaround using:

```
 select courname from courier where courid in (select courid from courierservice
 where cid=(select cid from city where cname='A')) and
 courid in (select courid from courierservice where cid=(select cid from city where cname='B'));
```

But this looks a little heavy.

It should, according to the documentation, work with the following All subquery:

```
select * from courier where courid in (select courid from courierservice 
where cid = all (select cid from city where cname='A' or cname='B'));
```

But it is returning an Empty Set.

Is there something missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's meaningless to use `= ALL`: how can a single `courierservice.cid` *simultaneously* be equal to more than one `city.cid`?  `ALL` is only ever used with a comparison operator that can match more than one value, such as `>=` or `<>`: see [Subqueries with `ALL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/all-subqueries.html).

However, you would do well to rewrite your query using `JOIN` (to be both more concise and more performant):

```
SELECT courname FROM courier NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   courid
  FROM     courierservice JOIN city USING (cid)
  WHERE    cname IN ('A', 'B')
  GROUP BY courid
  HAVING   SUM(cname='A') AND SUM(cname='B')
) t
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks. It was indeed meaningless. The above query didn't work. Now doing by the way of the course books, the following query works well: `select cs.courid from courierservice cs,city c where c.cname='A' and cs.cid=c.cid and exists (select cs2.cid from city c2,courierservice cs2 where cs2.courid=cs.courid and c2.cid=cs2.cid and c2.cname='B);`
Doing a bit more analysis, it is clear that it would get a little heavy any way! 
so Solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `cid = all` as `cid in` and it should work well.

Comment: cid in gives me a union. all couriers servicing either A or B. I need A and B

Comment: then use `and` instead of `or` in `cname='A' or cname='B'`

Answer (score 0):

`ALL()` returns a set. But when you compare using `'='` it compares with element. So a element can't be compared with a set. If you want to know if that element is inside the set then you have to use `IN` clause instead of `'='`